# Previous and Next Button function to VBA Data Entry form is not working

Tags: excel, vba

Previous Record and Next Record sub routine is not working. I marked with 1 and 2. These two navigation bars (1&2) works on the what is entered on WaypointId.

Say for example, if I say  waypoint id=1235, then next record should appear in a data entry form.  My vba code is first search the row number of waypoint id in observation sheet and then I decrease the row number by 1 for displaying previous record and increase the row number by 1 for next record. Depends on the functionality it shows data in the Data Entry Form.

My VBA code is not working for those two things. Attach workbook with name [Problem-1.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W5vjWivRrFA6mcxfXPYRJprwC24IRRos/view?usp=sharing) See Navigation Control Module.

```
Sub FindRecord(WyPt)

    Dim Value As String
    WyPtRow = 0
    
    ReadRow = 2
    Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2)
    
    While Value <> ""
        
        If WyPt = Value Then
            
            WyPtRow = ReadRow
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
        ReadRow = ReadRow + 1
        Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2)
    Wend
    
End Sub

 Sub ViewPreviousRecord()

    Set DEFrm = Sheets("DataEntryForm")
    Set ObsData = Sheets("Observations")
    
    Dim WyPt As String
    
    WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.Cells(6, 2))
    
    Call FindRecord(WyPt)
                
    LastRow = WyPtRow - 1
    
    With DEFrm
    
        .Cells(6, 2).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value 'WaypointID
        .Cells(6, 4).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value 'ObsType
        
        .Cells(8, 2).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 4).Value 'Date
        .Cells(8, 4).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 5).Value  'LoggedBy
    End With
End Sub

Sub ViewNextRecord()

Set DEFrm = Sheets("DataEntryForm")
Set ObsData = Sheets("Observations")
Dim WyPt As String

WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.Cells(6, 2))

Call FindRecord(WyPt)
            
LastRow = WyPtRow + 1

With DEFrm

    .Cells(6, 2).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value 'WaypointID
    .Cells(6, 4).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value 'ObsType
    .Cells(35, 10).Value = ObsData.Cells(LastRow, 115)   'Photo4Desc

   
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There's too much code in that file to review. You could help yourself *a lot* by creating two methods, one which takes a row of data as an argument and loads it into the form, and another which populates the form content to a specified row in your data sheet.  That will remove a ton of duplication from your code and make troubleshooting a lot easier.

Comment: Even better - add a new row above the column names in your "Observations" sheet, and populate that with the corresponding cell address for each matching cell on "DataEntryForm" - then you don't have a long series of lines to populate/save the form data, and your code is even easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most important procedure in your project.

```
Sub DisplayRecord(ByVal Rs As Long)
    ' 235
    
    Dim Arr         As Variant                  ' Data from row Rs in database
    Dim Target()    As String                   ' Dashboard addresses matching Arr
    Dim i           As Long                     ' loop counter: Arr(Index)
    
    ' cell addresses are aligned with column numbers in database (-2)
    Arr = "B6,D6,B8,D8,G6,H6,G7,H7,G8,H8,B11,C11,D11,E11,F11,G11,H11,I11"
    Arr = Arr & ",B14,C14,D14,E14,F14,G14,B17,C17,D17,E17,F17,G17"
    Arr = Arr & ",I14,J14,I15,J15,I16,J16,I17,J17,B20,C20,D20,E20,F20,G20"
    Arr = Arr & ",B23,C23,D23,E23,F23"
    Arr = Arr & ",I20,J20,K20,I21,J21,K21,I2,J22,K22,I23,J23,K23"
    Arr = Arr & ",B26,C26,D26,E26,F26,G26,H26,I26,J26,K26"
    Arr = Arr & ",B27,C27,D27,E27,F27,G27,H27,I27,J27,K27"
    Arr = Arr & ",B28,C28,D28,E28,F28,G28,H28,I28,J28,K28"
    Arr = Arr & ",B29,C29,D29,E29,F29,G29,H29,I29,J29,K29"
    Arr = Arr & ",B32,H32,I32,J32,H33,I33,J33,H34,I34,J34,H35,I35,J35"
    Target = Split(Arr, ",")
    
    With Sheets("Observations")
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(Rs, 1), .Cells(Rs, 115)).Value
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' speed up execution
    For i = 2 To UBound(Arr, 2)               ' skip first database column
        Sheets("DataEntryForm").Range(Target(i - 2)).Value = Arr(1, i)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It displays the data of the row `Rs` given to it as an argument. You already have a function that finds the row number needed by the above procedure. Below please find an improvement.

```
Function RecordRow(ByVal WyPt As String) As Long
    ' 235
    ' return the row number where WyP was found or 0

    Dim Fnd     As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Observations")
        Set Fnd = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Set Fnd = Fnd.Find(WyPt, , LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            RecordRow = Fnd.Row
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The deal is simple: you give the Waypoint ID and receive the row number where it was found. If it isn't found the function returns 0, and that is how you avoid crashes.

With these two procedures in place you can easily call up the first and the last records.

```
Sub ViewFirstRecord()
    ' 235
    DisplayRecord 2
End Sub

Sub ViewLastRecord()
    ' 235
    
    With Worksheets("Observations")
        DisplayRecord .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Sub
```

The next and previous records are just a matter of finding the row number and displaying its data.

```
Sub ViewNextRecord()
    ' 235

    Dim Rs          As Long                 ' data source row
    
    Rs = RecordRow(Trim(Cells(6, 2).Value)) + 1
    If Rs > 1 Then
        With Worksheets("Observations")
            If Rs <= .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Then
                DisplayRecord Rs
            Else
                MsgBox "No more records to show.", vbInformation, "Last record"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub ViewPreviousRecord()
    ' 235

    Dim Rs          As Long                 ' data source row
    
    Rs = RecordRow(Trim(Cells(6, 2).Value)) - 1
    If Rs > 1 Then
        DisplayRecord Rs
    Else
        MsgBox "No more records to show.", vbInformation, "First record"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the whole code, you may be finding a problem with scope. It seems ViewPreviousRecord() is not able to see WyPtRow.
You can try adding
dim WyPtRow
Before the Sub FindRecord(WyPt) definition.

Another implementation would be changing the Sub for a function, and returning the WyPtRow value.